# Rebuilding the entire graph database

Tags: python, browser, neo4j, nodes, rebuild

I deleted all nodes in my neo4j DB using cypher query.
eg: match(p) detach delete p;
Then rebuilt the entire nodes of different labels and relationships through python code.
Now, when I run the query to match the nodes after the rebuild, the graph returns nothing.

1. I cleared my entire history of the browser cache.
2. I ran the rebuild code again and again and the process seems to be successful.
3. But on the browser, when I query the nodes, I see nothing.

Someone, please advise.

Thanks,
Sonia

Comment: hi sonia, could you please share the query you are using to import the data

Comment: The code i used had been working a 1000 times in the past.

Comment: Also, these are just nodes created for data imported from postgres DB. I cant share the code here as its our product code and is confidential.

Comment: Make sure your browser is connected to the correct neo4j server. In the browser, use the `:server status` command to verify that it is connected to the right URL.

Comment: Yes thanks. unfortunately the credentials were wrong